# React-Select when click on the options, the option background color changing strange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

i am using react-select library and got the problem as below.

When i click on the option, the option color is changing, i would keep the color and do not change. Even after that i try to click again the selected option which is selected before, the color is change to blue, it is strange.

Please refer the code in the sanbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-edison-kn2wuz?file=/src/index.js:1083-1089

Answer (score 1):

thanks to chatgpt, the answer is pefect!!!
adding the '&:hover'

```
backgroundColor: isFocused || isHovered ? "#E6FFFB" : "transparent",
      color: "black",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "#E6FFFB"
      }
```

verified at the sanbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-goldwasser-ger7un?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding style for **:hover** pseudo class, the same style should be added for **:active** pseudo class. Because the option would still change color otherwise when moving mouse away while keeping the button pressed. Here is the code:

```
backgroundColor: isFocused || isHovered ? "#E6FFFB" : "transparent",
  color: "black",
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: isFocused || isHovered ? "#E6FFFB" : "transparent"
    color: "black"
  },
  "&:active": {
    backgroundColor: isFocused || isHovered ? "#E6FFFB" : "transparent"
    color: "black"
  }
```